# Application of Schwinger-Keldysh formalism in various topics except cosmology

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, non-equilibrium, applied-physics

I want to find some theories or models on [Schwinger-Keldysh formalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keldysh_formalism) (in-in formalism) focusing on flat spacetime in terms of correlation functions. For example, I know there are many applications for cosmology, i.e., applying in-in formalism to compute the 2-point function and so on.

Focusing on the path integral formulation, this formulation has a rich structure. But how about the correlation functions?  In cosmology 2-point correlators are related to power spectrum analysis and higher point correlation functions can be testified with more precision data from observation. So application on cosmological backgrounds like FRW or de-sitter background and computing 2-point or higher point correlation functions seems plausible job.

But how about other areas?

After some searching, I realized that Schwinger-Keldysh formalism can work fine on non-equilibrium processes and hydrodynamics. Then what physics can be done for 2-point/higher point functions? (I mean what is the meaning of correlator functions in those area?)

The reference I found for hydrodynamics relating to Schwinger-Keldysh, usually states effective field theory, or doubling degrees of freedom. So in a sense, they rewrite or re-establish the path integral formulation via Schwinger-Keldysh, not focusing on correlators.

What can be inferred from correlators? are there any physical phenomena or observable regarding non-equilibrium or any other theories regarding $n$-point correlators using Schwinger-Keldysh formalism?